# Registering required units on adding a component onto a form fails under Lazarus

Tags: lazarus, fpc

Lazarus 0.9.30.4

I am developing a component that requires several units to be added into the unit `uses` clause when the component is dropped onto a form.

From [this](http://wiki.freepascal.org/Extending_the_IDE) article I discovered the way to set the designer hooks and add required files into a project with the possibility to add the unit to the `uses` clause.

The code sample:

```
procedure TTestComponent.DoCompAdded(APersistent: TPersistent; Select: boolean);
var
  oProj: TLazProject;
  oFile: TLazProjectFile;
begin
  oProj := LazarusIDE.ActiveProject;
  oFile := oProj.CreateProjectFile('X:\Unit path\AddonUnit.pas');
  oFile.IsPartOfProject := True;
  oProj.AddFile(oFile, True);
end;

constructor TTestComponent.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  GlobalDesignHook.AddHandlerPersistentAdded(@DoCompAdded);
end;

procedure Register;
begin
  RegisterComponents('AAA',[TTestComponent]);
end;
```

On debugging I made sure that the handler was called, a unit `AddonUnit` was added to the project (I iterated thru all the files inside `oProj` object) but that led to a zero result: actually nothing was added to the project or to the `uses` clause.

Moreover, I found that project files collection `oProj.Files[index]` returns currently opened editor files and not the files included into the project.

Am I missing something or is there another way to include required units to `uses` clause or to the project?